# Why is the Spring/Flex/BlazeDS Messaging service-adapter not called?

Tags: java, apache-flex, spring, blazeds

I have attached a service-adapter to a spring message-destination as follows:

```
<flex:message-destination 
    id="secured-chat" 
    send-security-constraint="trusted" 
    subtopic-separator="." 
    service-adapter="secured-chatAdapter" 
    allow-subtopics="true" />
```

The init methods are called during the bean's initialization, and I get "invoke" messages when new messages are sent.

However, allowSubcribe and other methods are never called.  Are there any common causes of this problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was that the Consumers had not defined subtopics.  Because there were no subtopics being subscribed to, the subtopic specific permissions methods were not being called.

Comment: Doh!  I've never worked with sub-topics before.  How did you work it out?

Comment: I think it was from reading through the sourcecode.  :)  Either that or finally reading the javadocs the right way.

Answer (score 1):

I've found these kinds of BlazeDS problems to be tricky to diagnose.  My recommendation is to configure very verbose logging.  There is more details on the [Flex 2 Developer's Guide: Configuring server-side service logging](http://livedocs.adobe.com/flex/2/docs/wwhelp/wwhimpl/common/html/wwhelp.htm?context=LiveDocs_Parts&file=00001099.html)

Edit `./WEB-INF/flex/services-congif.xml` and add/modify the logging node to something like this:

```
<logging>
    <target class="flex.messaging.log.ServletLogTarget" level="debug">
        <properties>
            <prefix>[BlazeDS] </prefix>
            <includeDate>true</includeDate>
            <includeTime>true</includeTime>
            <includeLevel>true</includeLevel>
            <includeCategory>true</includeCategory>
        </properties>
        <filters>
            <pattern>Endpoint.*</pattern>
            <pattern>Service.*</pattern>
            <pattern>Message.*</pattern>
            <pattern>Message.Command.*</pattern>
            <pattern>MessageSelector</pattern>
            <pattern>Service.Message</pattern>
        </filters>
    </target>
</logging>
```

There are other filter patters you could add from the link above which might be important for you.  If you don't see the culprit then post more of your `services-config.xml` and log files here and we'll see what we can do.

Quick warning: It can get very verbose.  Don't do this on your production server!